# Restore from code doesn't work and provides no errors

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, database-restore

I'm having a difficult time restoring several databases with my C# script. It's also not providing any errors -- it just does nothing.

Here's the code:

```cs
// Connect to SQL Server
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVERNAME;" + "Integrated Security=SSPI;" + "Connection timeout=60");

StreamWriter logFile = new StreamWriter(@"F:\Backups\log.txt");

try{
    conn.Open();
}catch(Exception e){
    string errorTxt = "There was an error connecting to the server: " + e.ToString();
    logFile.WriteLine(errorTxt);
}

// Get Directory
DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(@"F:\Backups\SERVERNAME\");

foreach(FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles()){

    // We need to get the DB name:
    string filename = fi.Name.ToString();
    int bkpIndex = filename.IndexOf("_backup");

    string sql = "USE master RESTORE DATABASE " + filename.Substring(0, bkpIndex) + " FROM DISK = '" + fi.FullName + "' WITH REPLACE";

    try{
        Console.WriteLine("Restoring {0}.", filename.Substring(0, bkpIndex));
        logFile.WriteLine("SQL: {0}", sql);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        logFile.WriteLine("Error restoring {0}: " + ex.ToString(), filename.Substring(0, bkpIndex));
    }

}

logFile.Close()
conn.Close()
```

Comment: When you debug it - does it execute the command? And does the logfile get flushed to disk or does it error too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not executing the command anywhere... Try ExecuteNonQuery!

e.g.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: That's it... It's weird, though. I thought I tried that and it asked for an argument... maybe I clicked on a different Intellisense tag or something...